# Is the table designer not supported for memory optimized tables?

Tags: ssms

If I right click a table, I get the normal designer option:

[image]

But if I right click a memory optimized table, the designer is missing:

[image]

The server is 2016 and I've tried it in SSMS 16, 17, and 18.3. Is there just no designer support for memory optimized tables? I can usually drop and recreate the table when I need to make a change. That's what SSMS does anyway. But it's a pain in the ass when there are FKs involved.

Comment: What are the options of: `Script table as...`?

Comment: @McNets The usual options. That hasn't changed and I can do it that way. But doing it that way requires me to figure out every table in the FK chain, dropping each table from the bottom (including data), and then creating everything again when I'm done making my change. It's the same thing SSMS does, but it does it automatically. The designer makes it a lot easier. Especially if I have to make a lot of changes.